# ruby-debug how to go inside a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-debug

what is the command to go inside a function using ruby-debug?
Example

```
class Hello
  def meth1
    debugger
    meth2
  end

  def meth2
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

I want to go inside the meth2 and see the execution.Need similar commands like n(next),c(continue),l(current line)

Comment: can you try `step` :)

Comment: how to come out of the method?

Comment: i'm not sure how to do that.  try the different list of commands found by typing `help` while in the debugger prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you searched very hard since Google had a number of useful pages.

Perhaps you'll find "[Debugging with ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html)" useful, especially [`Step`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html#Step), `Next` and `Finish`.